# Best approach to showing or hiding dynamic content in iOS

Tags: ios

I've been doing iOS for a while now, but when it comes to dynamically hiding / showing elements, I'm a bit lost.
Coming from Android, I'm used to being able to simply set views to visibility gone, but this doesn't exist on iOS.

So let's say I have the following scenario:

[image]

Basically I want to have a table, but the table should not fill the entire view controller. Instead it should leave place for optionally either a button, a multiline label, or possibly both at the bottom (if visible, these should be fixed, not scroll).

One way to solve this would be to use auto layout and modify constraints, like adding a zero height constraint. But that would make iOS kill one of the other constraints, which would make it hard to change it again. For the label, I wouldn't always want to have a height constraint, because it could be multiline, and should take the size it needs.
Maybe it's easier to skip autolayout here and modify frames instead, I don't know.

My question is: What approach would be best here?
Is there some other way of doing this I haven't thought of, or do I have to try to do what I described above?

I'm not primarily looking for code (code can be ok), but I'm more interested in a description of how it can be done.
I'd like to support iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem had a variety of solutions, and opinion based, but I'm facing such questions a lot, when I don't know what to choose and what would be the "right thing".

So, I my opinion, the best solution here is using autolayout, you need to set height of label manually, but you have a few methods for this, at least you can play with it and if you don't succeed ask question about it. Using frames, you'll face same problem of calculating height, right? But with auto layout, you only need to set height, vertical space to 0, when you need to hide message.

You can also use constrains with priority lower 1000, and remove completely constraints from message (button, label) if you don't need it at all anymore.

For example, taking your layout image, you can make UIView with subviews: button, label. Top constraint connect to the UITableView, other constraints to the sides.Label and button will calculate the view's height. The only question here is label height.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. It does seem like autolayout might be the best approach here. The problem I've had with it in the past is that it will break another constraint when I add the height constraint. Maybe different priority values could help here, or that I control removal/readding of other constraints myself.

Comment: @user3533716 Try to set different priority values or set height constraint as >= or <= value it helps. And it's easier than removing adding constraints in code at runtime, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

So in ios assuming that the background of both these objects is opaque only the front most view in the Heirarchy will be visible and interactable, An easy solution would be to change the different frames of these two things you need and make sure they are in the back of your view heirachy, and when you need them to appear use `view.bringSubviewToFront(mySubview)` and `view.pushSubviewToBack(mySubview)` to make it disappear again. View obviously would be referring to main view of your view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would cause the views to overlap the table. I wouldn't want to obscure the bottom of the tableview, you should still be able to scroll all the way to the bottom of it.